# MP4s skip when put into lightworks

Tags: lightworks

Below I've included a link to a video demonstrating my problem. The audio sounds fine until I put it into lightworks with another audio track and begin editing. The first clip is both audio tracks together, the second is the top audio track, the third is the bottom audio track, and the last is what it's supposed to sound like.

Answer (score 1):

- Don't do sync work with the MP4s/H264 codec. Use proper codecs (ProRes or DNxHD).
- Work with .wav or .aif audio files.
- Keep an eye on your audio file sample rates.

Lightworks is much less forgiving to small errors than other programs are. Be super precise.